# A command to replace \middle| when it's missing?

Tags: plain-tex, primitives

I'm using this LaTeX plugin for a Wiki (Confluence, blech), and it doesn't support the `\middle|` command. I'm guessing it doesn't have eTex primitives or some such backwardness. Anyway, I guess I can write things like

```
\newcommand{\fakemiddlebar}[2]{{\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\left.\vphantom{{#1}{#2}}\right|}}
\newcommand{\condset}[2]{\left\{ #1 \mathrel{\fakemiddlebar{#1}{#2}} #} \right\}}
```

(improved as per @egreg's suggestion).

**Edit:** But I want to do better! I want to have an argument-less command with the same effect is `\middle|`. Also, I can't `\include` or `\usepackage`. Is that possible?

Comment: See http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=braket for more on the `\middle` command and the `braket` package.

Answer (score 14):

You get the same result with `\condset{x\in X}{x<\frac{1}{2}}` as

```
\left\{x\in X\middle|x<\frac{1}{2}}
```

by modifying your macros into

```
\newcommand{\fakemiddlepipe}[2]{{\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\left.\vphantom{{#1}{#2}}\right|}}
\newcommand{\condset}[2]{\left\{ #1 \fakemiddlepipe{#1}{#2} #2 \right\}}
```

Note the additional pair of braces around the body of `\fakedmiddlepipe` and the `\kern` instruction that takes away the space added by `\left.`. Of course there would be no space around the pipe, so the final definition might be

```
\newcommand{\condset}[2]{\left\{ #1 \mathrel{\fakemiddlepipe{#1}{#2}} #2 \right\}}
```

so that the result of `\condset{x\in X}{x<\frac{1}{2}}` would be the same as the more correct

```
\left\{x\in X\;\middle|\;x<\frac{1}{2}}
```

(and you could even remove the additional pair of braces in the definition of `\fakemiddlepipe`; but I'd leave them for other possible usages).

[image]

Comment: grrr..  2 minutes. 2 minutes! `:-(`

Comment: @morbusg we'll never beat egreg! =)

Comment: @morbusg Sorry, this is the kind of questions that fascinates me the most. :)

Comment: `;-)` The difference I had was the negative kern of `\nulldelimiterspace` after the `\right.`, and wrapping the whole `\left`/`\right` into a `\mathord`. The spacing looked the same as with a `\middle` that way.

Comment: @morbusg Those are really equivalent: `${something}$` and `$\mathord{something}$` are the same.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course! (+1)

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for the improvement, but that's not what I was aiming for... let me clarify that.

Comment: @morbusg: You'll get your chance in a moment, don't worry.

Comment: @morbusg I won't answer, I promise. :)

Comment: Eyal, @egreg: Aditya's answer is actually so clever I'm just going to upvote his :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are only interested in `\middle|` (and not any other delimiter),  just use `\vrule`.

```
$$\left\{x\in X\;\vrule\; x< {1 \over 2} \right\}$$
\bye
```

Comment: Hmmm... so what's the use in \middle| then?

Comment: You can use any delimiter with `\middle`: `\middle\Vert`, `\middle\)`, etc. (Not that I can think of a reason why the latter will be needed. Note that the `bracket` package internally use `\vrule` for non eTeX engines.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mico suggests, the [braket](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/braket/) package has the solution: Change the catcode of `|`, and use `|` instead of `\middle|` . You just have to be careful not to use it out of a group by mistake.